# How to stop mousegrabber in another function

Tags: awesome-wm

I am creating a tasklist with drag and drop.

In the `widget_template` `create_callback` function I am using this code:

```lua
self:connect_signal("button::press",
function(_, lx, ly, button, mods)
   capi.mousegrabber.run(
   function()
     return true
     end, "hand") 
end)
self:connect_signal("button::release",
function(_, lx, ly, button, mods)
    capi.mousegrabber.stop()
end)
```

Mousegrabber does not stop when mouse is released and I don't understand why.

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't rely on `"button::release"` when the mousegrabber is running.

Comment: You are correct and I am stupid for forgetting about that. Though I immediately got another problem if I do ```return mouse.is_left_mouse_button_pressed``` it only does it once. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I meant  ```mouse.is_left_mouse_button_pressed``` returns nil

Comment: The idea of the mousegrabber is to *not* have the mouse events work. That includes AwesomeWM own APIs. The mousegrabber callbacks are the only place which is expected to have usable mouse "things" working. It would not be impossible to implement an API where you can enable some of the other things while the mousegrabber is running, but this isn't that the current implementation does. It grabs the mouse events and pass them to the callback (only).

Comment: Alright, sorry if it gets repetitive but then how should I get the mouse release to stop the mousegrabber? Because button::press signal starts the mousegrabber but I don't understand how to stop it when mouse is released.

Comment: You can get it from the table passed to the mousegrabber itself. It has more than just the `x`/`y`. It also has the button statuses and modkeys. You have to keep the "old" state of `whatever.buttons` (where whatever is the name of the run() callback argument variable) and check in the next event if the state has changed. I will see if I can improve the documentation, right now I admit it isn't obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Emmanuel Lepage Vallee the solution I found looks like this:

```lua
self:connect_signal("button::press",
function(_, lx, ly, button, mods)
   capi.mousegrabber.run(
   function(mouse)
     return mouse.buttons[1]
   end, "hand") 
end)
```

Mousegrabber disables any mouse events happening that's why you can't rely on `button::release` signal to activate another function. The only way to interact with the mouse is through the mousegrabber function `mouse` parameter

`mouse.buttons[NUMBER]` is an undocumented property which you can use. It returns `true` if it is pressed.